Dataset of gendered nouns that designate humans
I'm looking for a dataset of gendered nouns that designate humans.
Examples of gendered nouns that designate humans:

actor/actress
anchorman/anchorwoman
ballerina/ballerino
brother-in-law/sister-in-law
man/woman
men/women

I am mostly interested in English but I am also interested in other languages.

Have you looked at the category Nouns with other-gender equivalents by language on wiktionary and its sub-categories and pages?
If it's for language teaching purposes, it may be exactly what you're looking for.
However, if it's for some task related to programming, NLP, and whatnot, it will require some heavy webscraping and data cleaning to get something usable, as the pages are not in a standardized format. You may also want to filter out pages that do not describe humans, i.e. pages that do not belong to the subset of the "People", "Male people", or "Female people" categories.
But your question does not mention any requirements relative to the data format, and does not mention what it will be used for. Anyway, this is a very comprehensive dataset, for many languages. It's just quite difficult to get it in a usable format if you want to use it for some programming task. Not impossible, though, and you should be able to retrieve at least a part of the data in a usable form for programming.

thanks, for NLP. Nice list!

Did you look into these following platforms for that data:

wordnet


Open Multilingual WordNet

